# Finding volume of solid using two methods

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, volume

The question is: The region bounded by $y=\frac{1}{x}, y=0, x=1, x=2$ is rotated about the $y$-axis, thus creating a solid. Compute the volume using the Shell and Slicing method.

This is what I have thus far:

[image]

> **Shell method**
>
> Radius of the shell = x
>
> Height of the shell = $\frac{1}{x}$
>
> Volume: $\int_1^2 2π × x ×\frac{1}{x} dx$
>   = $2π\int_1^2 dx$ = $2π$
>
> **Slicing method**
>
> I tried to set the outer radius to be $1/y$ and the inner radius is
>   $1$, but I don't know what the limits of the integral. Am I doing it
>   wrong? Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to break it into two regions, since the functions which maintain the outer and inner radius are not the same throughout $0\le y\le 1$.

$$R_1:\ \ 0\le y\le \dfrac{1}{2}, \ \ \ 1\le x\le 2$$
$$R_2:\ \ \dfrac{1}{2}\le y\le1, \ \ \ 1\le x\le 1/y$$

Then

$$V = \underbrace{\pi\int_0^{1/2} (2)^2-(1)^2\  dy}_{R_1} \ +\  \underbrace{\pi\int_{1/2}^1 (1/y)^2 - (1)^2 \ dy}_{R_2}$$